# How to get rid of the changes that are pulled into my local repo from a remote fork that I had added

Tags: git, github

I am using git & github. I had added a remote fork to my repo & pulled changes from a branch on that remote fork. Following is what I have done

```
git remote add some_remote_fork remote_fork_ssh_link.git
git pull some_remote_fork a_branch_on_remote_fork
```

Now *I want to get rid of the remote fork & also the changes which the branch brought into my repo*. To remove the remote fork I did:-

```
git remote rm some_remote_fork
```

But the changes that I pulled from `a_branch_on_remote_fork` are still present on my repo. I tried `git pull`, `git pull origin/master` & more. But cannot get rid of the changes.

`git status` shows no changed files but says:
    `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.`

**How should I get rid of the changes that are pulled into my local repo from remote fork?** How should I switch back & get in sync with my `origin/master` or called `personal/master` in some cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git reset --hard origin/master`.

Answer (score 2):

git pull will do two things: it does a `git fetch` and then a `git merge` where it merges branches that have been setup to be merged in your config

you can try using `git reset --hard` to reset to a previous state.

If the pull was the last thing you did then

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```